# Angular2 /page Failed to load resource: status 404

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

pls help me. I don't know why it doesn't work. Why server sends me this status? What am i doing wrong? What is wrong with this code? Funny thing is that i can get to this page but when i press f12 ( in console ) i am getting this error -> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/registration 
This is my SO EASY CODE.

app.ts

```
import './sass/style.scss'
import 'reflect-metadata'
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RootComponent } from './components/root.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './components/registration.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      RootComponent,
      RegistrationComponent
   ],
     imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     routing
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
    })

    export class AppModule {}

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { RegistrationComponent } from './components/registration.component';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

route.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'root-component',
  template: `
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class RootComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I had to add `{ useHash: true}` this to my routing.

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true});
```

Now it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a webserver rewriting mechanism: Angular knows what to do with `/registration`, but your webserver doesn’t. Which means that you need to configure your webserver to pass requests to non-existing files to Angular, i.e. `index.html` (or whatever you Ang2 starting point is).

Assumed you use Apache, the most simple thing to do is:

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Alternatively (or if you use a server which does not support anything like this), you can switch to Angular’s `HashLocationStrategy`.

Comment: But yesterday this works :D ( lel ) I am doing npm start ( like yesterday, they changed smth? )

Comment: Doing it on webpack